# Sketch app for Mac or PC

Tags: macos

does anyone know a sketch application for mac or pc, particularly for sketching mockup iphone/android apps?  I have searched google but only found one called sketch app, but this one is dependent on OmniGraffle.  If anyone knows if such software ever exist, please help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out Balsamiq:
http://www.balsamiq.com/